# check "isDefined" and map to "get" together

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I do the following more efficiently:

```
myoptionList.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get)
```

This will take two iterations time, is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  The simplest is probably `flatten`.  Since `Option` is implicitly convertible to `Iterable`, you can `flatten` a list of `Options` in much the same way you would a list of lists:

```
myOptionList.flatten
```

You can also use `flatMap` in much the same way.  Here are a few options:

```
myOptionList.flatMap(x => x)
myOptionList.flatMap(identity(_))
myOptionList.flatMap(Option.option2Iterable)
myOptionList.flatMap[Int,List[Int]](identity)
```

You can also use `collect`.  `collect` takes a `PartialFunction` as an argument.  If a match is found, then the value is mapped according to the function.  Otherwise it is filtered out.  So here, you could match on just `Some(x)` and map to `x` (so that all `Nones` are filtered out).  This option is the most general, and will allow you to apply even more refined logic if you so desire.

```
myOptionList.collect { case Some(x) => x }

//Example of more complex logic:
myOptionList.collect {
    case Some(x) if x % 2 == 0 => x / 2
}
```

I'd also like to mention that in general when you have complex logic that takes more than one operation on a list, but you don't want to traverse over the list multiple times, you can use `view`:

```
myOptionList.view.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get) //Will only traverse list once!
```

Comment: Instead of `(x => x)` more usual used `myOptionList.flatMap(identity)`

Comment: @Yury For many such cases you're right, but I don't think that works in the list of `Option` case, because the type inference only works when you spell out the lambda

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `myOptionList` is a `List[Option[T]]` for some `T` you can use `flatten`:

```
val values = myOptionList.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `collect`:

```
myOptionList.collect {
  case Some(x) => x
}
```

`collect` both maps and filters in a single step.